# Python : List of string in key value pairs to map

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string as given below

```
print(schema)
a:int,b:string,c:int,d:decimal(18,2)
```

I have another list as given below

```
list1= [ 'a,','b']
```

I want to convert this string schema to map so that i can look up into that map for further processing.

I tried options like

```
from operator import methodcaller
y = map(methodcaller("split", ":"), schema)
```

The result is

```
[['a', 'int'], ['b', 'string'], ['c', 'int'], ['d',  'decimal(18'], ['2)']]
```

I want to look up list1 in dictionary to  get the values.

ie. for a in list1 i need to look up in y and get the 'int' value.

I am new to python. Please help me in getting this logic implemented.

Comment: How are you getting the `schema` string? Part of the problem here is that your values are comma-separated, but your values also contain commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problematic schema string, because of the `decimal(18,2)` value. You should change the separator of the schema or the decimal for an easier split, like: `a:int;b:string;c:int;d:decimal(18,2)`, but if you cannot do that, it could work with regular expressions like:

```py
import re

schema = "a:int,b:string,c:int,d:decimal(18,2)"
regex = re.compile("\w+:\w+(?:\(\d+,\d+\))?")

dictionary = {}
for pair in regex.finditer(schema):
    k, v = pair.group(0).split(":")
    dictionary[k] = v

list1 = ['a', 'b']

for e in list1:
    print("key:" + e + ", value:" + dictionary[e])
```

if you can change the schema then you can use simple a split:

```py
schema = "a:int;b:string;c:int;d:decimal(18,2)"

dictionary = {}
for pair in schema.split(";"):
    k, v = pair.split(":")
    dictionary[k] = v
```